# Sorting array of struct in c

Tags: c, sorting, struct

The function below sorts my struct by volume.

```
void selection_sort(struct cylinder my_cylinders[], int n)
{
  int i, largest = 0;
  double temp;

  if (n == 1)
    return;

  for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if (my_cylinders[i].volume > my_cylinders[largest].volume)
      largest = i;

  if (largest < n - 1) {
    temp = my_cylinders[n - 1];   // ** Line 77
    my_cylinders[n - 1] = my_cylinders[largest];
    my_cylinders[largest] = temp; // ** Line 79
  }
```

But when I try to compile I get the following errors:

```
cylinders.c:77: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘struct cylinder’
cylinders.c:79: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct cylinder’ from type ‘int’
```

And here is my struct

```
struct cylinder {
        double radius;
        double height;
        double weight;
        double volume;
};
```

And main

```
int i, counter = 0; 

fprintf(cFileOut, "#    Radius           Height          Volume          Weight\n");

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
{   
    while (fscanf(cFileIn, "%lf, %lf, %lf\n", &radius, &height,  &weight) != EOF)
{
   my_cylinders[counter].radius = radius;
   my_cylinders[counter].height = height;
   my_cylinders[counter].volume = volume;
   my_cylinders[counter].weight = weight;

   volume = PI * radius * radius * height;  
   fprintf(cFileOut, "%-d\t  %-12.6lf\t  %-12.6lf\t  %-12.6lf\t   %-12.6lf \n", 
    counter, radius, height, volume, weight);
    counter++;      
}
}

selection_sort(my_cylinders, counter);
```

I guess I understand the errors but not sure how to fix them. I've tried changing the types but I'm missing something when it comes to structs.

Comment: Which are line 77 and 79? And how are you calling it?

Comment: Your function is obviously not complete...

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I commented the line numbers in the code. Also just edited post with additional code.

Comment: @Deduplicator...thanks. Would you like to elaborate?

Comment: `temp = my_cylinders[n - 1];` temp is a number, but your cylinders array holds structs. You can't assign a struct to a double.

Comment: I think that `selection_sort` in the previous question did not have to be rewritten.

Comment: If the errors are fixed, what is it that your'e missing?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, thanks. I added struct cylinder temp instead of int temp and it compiles but still not sorting by volume

Comment: @ClsForCookies, just not sorting the output by volume

Comment: (step1) Read all record (and calculate `volume` then set member) into array. This step doesn't write to the file. (step 2) Do sort the array. (step 3) Write the array contents to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change type of temp from `double` to `struct cylinder`.

Also note that you are just finding the largest item from the struct based on volume and swapping it with the last index. That's not sorting.

To sort, you must call this function in a loop while decrementing the counter by 1 one each time.

Something like"

```
while(counter>=0){
  selection_sort(my_cylinders, counter);
  counter--;
}
```

and change the if condition inside the function as:

```
if (n == 0)// since n=0 will mean that last item has been reached
    return;
```